# Autodesk Viewer load saved markups from SVG file

Tags: node.js, autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I'm currently working with the Autodesk Viewer API to display and add markups to DWG files. I now can add markups and retrieve them. 
I saved one markup as a svg file and now, I'm looking for a way to load the SVG file to display the markup on my viewer.
Do you have any idea on how I could do that?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Markups can be loaded using the [loadMarkups](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v6/reference/javascript/markupscore/#loadmarkups-markupstring-layerid) method. Here's an example: https://developer.api.autodesk.com/viewingservice/v1/viewers/docs/tutorial-feature_markup.html#saving-and-loading-markups.

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to check this out